# C# Windows Form Application Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#, windows, exception, error-handling, crash

I created a WFA for my friend's birthday, made a setup and sent the app to my friend. In the back end of the code I had to manually change the background wallpaper of the program on a button click and I used  **this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(@C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Birthday_candles.jpg");**

I did the same thing with **System.Media.Player.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = @"C\Users\Admin\Downloads\Happy.wav";**

How do I add them on my setup file or something like this because if I delete, change location of those two components I get a "Unhandled exception has occured in your application. If you click Continue, the app will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the app will close immediately."

Is there any solution with the code, setup or anything so it saves the files and keeps them even if the files are deleted or their address is changed.

Thank you!

Comment: Add them as embedded resource.

Comment: Either as a resource, or put the filename in as a config string, then you can change it in the config file. You should have error handling anyway, in case the file doesn't exist or can't be opened

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the resources on the Properties > Resources.resx. Accessing the image would look like as follows:

```
PanelName.Image = Properties.Resources.ImageName;
```

You can add the code snippet on a button click event.